# Need help making a credit holder?

Tags: python

I'm halfway through making a vending machine in python, but I've hit a snag. I'm doing this task as a controlled assessment, and there are certain guidelines I have to follow, one such being that the vending machine should have a credit holder to tell you how much money you have. The problem with mine is that it doesn't register numbers past £0.99. I was hoping if someone could point out the mistake I made, or give me a little help?

```
angel= float(0.00)
repeat = True
while repeat==True:
    choice=int(input("""Please select how much you would like to enter

    1.10p
    2.20p
    3.50p
    4.£1 """))

    if choice==1:
        angel=(angel + 0.10)
    if choice==2:
        angel=(angel + 0.20)
    if choice==3:
        angel=(angel + 0.50)       
    if angel==4:
        angel=(angel + 1.00)
    choice2=str(input("Would you like to input more money to your ballance? y/n"))
    if choice2== "y":
        repeat= True
    else:
        repeat= False
        print("Your balance currently stands at £",angel)
        store=int(input("""Please select what you would like to buy

    1. Pleb bar £2
    2. Geb bar £0.10
    3. Plebsi £1
    4. Goke £0.50
    5. Jeb bar £1.50 : """))
```

That's what I have so far; it's very simple but I need to make sure this credit wallet works. Thanks for the help, everything's appreciated.

Comment: Is another such guideline that you should be doing your own work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should this:

```
if angel==4:
    angel=(angel + 1.00)
```

instead be this:

```
if choice==4:
    angel=(angel + 1.00)
```

Comment: oK SO IM incredibly stupid, i never even relaised that, thank you so much